# info.plist and app id creation

Tags: iphone

have developed an application for my clients, in the info.plist i have  :

bundle identifier  com.myCompagnyDomain.theApp

Bundle name        §{PRODUCT_NAME}

Now i would like to create a an app Id to distribute the app to the apple store.

What i will put in the :
Description
Bundle Seed ID (App ID Prefix)
Bundle Identifier (App ID Suffix)

myCompagnydomain is the domain name of my compagy ( not of my client), is this a problem ??

An other question,

My client give to me the user name and password of his account and he would like that i submit to him the application ( ziped).can i sign it with his account and submit to him the ziped app ? how i can do this ?

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bundle name field You have put string like string in Provisioning Profile, when you create on Apple  Provisioning portal.

Usually it is "com.'yourcompanyname'.'yourappname'", for example "com.apple.xcode".

But you can write any other string, your dog name, or your name, or project name, for example "com.xcode" or "xcode" or "bob007".